# Spring JMS header boolean could not be resolved

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

i have an error in a Spring JMS Listener version 5

i have set a header to a boolean value .
i checked the message header on IBM mq browser and the value is correctly set ;
but when the listener consumes the message the header could not be resolved .
this is the error:

MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'VERSION_MESSAGE' for method parameter type [class java.lang.Boolean],

here is the listener

```
@JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_INTERNE, containerFactory = "ListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessageReceived(String message,                
                                  @Header (value = JmsHeaders.VERSION_MESSAGE) Boolean version)
```

here is the value of the JmsHeaders.VERSION_MESSAGE is JmsHeaders

public static final String VERSION_MESSAGE="VERSION_MESSAGE";

i tried another approach where i removed header from listener like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_INTERNE, containerFactory = "ListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessageReceived(javax.jms.Message message)

boolean version=message.getBooleanProperty(JmsHeaders.VERSION_MESSAGE);
```

i have no error but the boolean value is always to false.

extra infomation ,
the listener container is overriden like this :

```
@Override
protected Message receiveMessage(MessageConsumer consumer) throws JMSException {
    BatchMessage batch = new BatchMessage(batchSize);       
    while (!batch.releaseAfterMessage(super.receiveMessage(consumer))) ;
    return batch.getMessages().isEmpty() ? null : batch;
}
```

and the overriden method always returns false:

```
  @Override
        public boolean getBooleanProperty(String s) throws JMSException {
            return false;
        }
```

now i understand why i always get false ,but how could i make it reruen the correct value?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

finally i found a solution to my question,
given that my defaultListenerContainerFactory was overriden and when we receive a message this method is executed

```
@Override
protected Message receiveMessage(MessageConsumer consumer) throws JMSException {
    BatchMessage batch = new BatchMessage(batchSize);       
    while (!batch.releaseAfterMessage(super.receiveMessage(consumer))) ;
    return batch.getMessages().isEmpty() ? null : batch;
}
```

so we dont have access to headers from the listener ,because we get the messages wrapped in batchMessage :

public class BatchMessage implements Message {

```
private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

private int batchSize;
```

that implemets Message Class:

```
package javax.jms;

import java.util.Enumeration;

public interface Message {
    int DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE = 2;
    int DEFAULT_PRIORITY = 4;
    long DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE = 0L;
    long DEFAULT_DELIVERY_DELAY = 0L;

    String getJMSMessageID() throws JMSException;

    void setJMSMessageID(String var1) throws JMSException;

    long getJMSTimestamp() throws JMSException;

    void setJMSTimestamp(long var1) throws JMSException;

    byte[] getJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes() throws JMSException;
```

what it means that all the JmsHeaders and Jms Data are inside Message ;

so i had to go through the List inside BatchMessage to get all JmsAttributes and Headers .

here is the Listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination = TARGETQUEUE, containerFactory = "BatchMessageListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessageReception(Message message) throws StockageQueueListenerException {

        try{

                    insererBatch((BatchMessage) message);
}
```